# Ошибки при использовании guard init

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gems

Читаю Ruby on Rails Tutorial. На шаге установки Guard возникла проблема:
после того, как сделаю `guard init`, получаю ошибки:

> 22:24:47 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/rspec' or '~/.guard/templates/rspec' or find class Guard::Rspec
>   22:24:47 - ERROR - Error is: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/simple/.guard/templates/rspec

Как исправить ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, забыли добавить бандлер: `bundle exec guard init`